# How to hide/encrypt Excel VBA cdo email password in code?

Tags: excel, vba, email, password-encryption, cdo.message

i use this method to send emails from Excel:

```
Dim Mail As New Message
Dim Config As Configuration
Set Config = Mail.Configuration

Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
Config(cdoSendUserName) = "sender@gmail.com"
Config(cdoSendPassword) = "password123"
Config.Fields.Update
```

But as you can see the password is shown as a plain text in the code.

How can i hide/encrypt that line (password) or this part/module of my vba-code? (I've read something about to make a dll from the code, but don't know how.)

Thank You!

Comment: You could make the user input the password before running the macro :)  `PW= InputBox("Give me some input")`

Comment: It depends on VBA skills of people seeing the code. If they have access to VBE and know a little VBA, independent of your encryption, they can use your decriptor in the moment of making comparison between the input password and the encrypted one.